# How to find min and max value in a array of objects

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and Javascript community. I have an array of objects(countries) and each object consists of years represented by key and its value(incomes).

How to get the minimum and maximum value of incomes across all the objects and its key to set the color legend?

Please find the link https://observablehq.com/d/287af954b6aaf349 of the project, hope it would help to explain the question.

Thank you for reading the questions.

Comment: I'm working on a similar data set as I learn myself d3js, check it out [here](https://observablehq.com/d/428e78c64b053d31), if you have any questions regarding my implementation let me know

Comment: @RicardoSanchez The interactive function gives me inspiration for my project. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the global maximum, you can use

```js
const max = d3.max(
    countries.map(country =>
        d3.max(Object.values(country))));

// 179000
```

What it does is iterate over the countries, grabbing from each country the maximum of all the values. Then, it takes the maximum of these maxima and returns that.

To also get the corresponding year, it becomes more complex. You can use `Object.entries` to get the key value pair, instead of just the value.
You can then manually loop over each country, updating the max value, and the corresponding year as you go

```js
data.reduce((max, country) => {
  const newMax = d3.max(Object.values(country));
  if(newMax > max.value) {
    return {
      year: Object.entries(country).find(([year, value]) => value === newMax)[0],
      value: newMax,
    };
  }
  return max;
}, {value: 0});

// {year: "2040", value: 179000}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another useful method backed in d3 is the `d3.extent()` function check [this article](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-extent)